# remove alaska and hawaii in d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I'm new to javascript and finding my way around [creating a chloropleth in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) but wanted to know how might I remove Alaska and Hawaii from the map and have only the contiguous 48 states? I am using the same us.json file as the one in the tutorial.

I find in the docs perhaps [maps.remove(key)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-map_set) might give a clue but I am not quite sure how to tell it to remove the two states specifically.

Or do I need a different us.json file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON file used in that example doesn't contain the immediate information necessary to remove those states -- there are only IDs of the counties, so you would have to figure out which counties to remove.

You can either prepare a JSON file that contains only the lower 48 states yourself, or get the files for the individual states you want from [here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries/USA) and combine them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the us.json file in the tutorial (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json) do seem to have the states with their respective id's (AK with id:2 and HI with id:15)?

Comment: I think the IDs are for counties only -- they are used to match the data used in the choropleth in the code.

Comment: If this answer isn't useful, please explain why.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just manually deleting the few counties within AK and HI in notepad to get what I needed.

Comment: There's a copy of the JSON file available [here](https://gist.github.com/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922). You can modify it by removing the entries for Alaska and Hawaii.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer the question. I run into this problem today. You can look into:

var projection = d3.geo.albers();

It will do the trick.

For further information, you can look at:

https://books.google.com/books?id=CUgjCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=us+map+without+alaska+d3.js&source=bl&ots=nHg15JX_ww&sig=jmHhFunUjKnIvx63GsnYEvXwyPs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9YeRVdfBHsa4-QHNl5ngDA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=us%20map%20without%20alaska%20d3.js&f=false

This is page 247 of Data Visualization with JavaScript By Stephen A. Thomas
Best. The example of this book created a map without AL and HI.